# How can I get current value of range slider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a question!! I have loaded from repo an angular directive called "angular-ranger" And I encountered with problem to get current value of  range slider. Please help me, how can I get the value from its directive?? You can download this one: https://github.com/JustMaier/angular-ranger

Comment: read example on github page, or put your code here

Comment: There is no example!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code in the example https://justmaier.github.io/angular-ranger/#demo, the min value is the one set on the model you set on the min-value and the max one in the max value so here value.min and value.max :

```
<div class="ranger ng-isolate-scope" min="0" max="20" step="1" min-value="value.min" max-value="value.max">
    <div class="ranger-scale">
        <div class="ranger-marker" tabindex="0" marker-value="3" style="left: 167px;"></div>
        <div class="ranger-fill" style="left: 167px; right: 108px;"></div>
        <div class="ranger-marker" tabindex="0" marker-value="100" style="left: 972px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx. I didn't notice it!

Answer (score 0):

http://justmaier.github.io/angular-ranger/#demo

```
<input id="min" name="min" type="number" ng-model="value.min" placeholder="Min" min="0" max="18" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-min ng-valid-max ng-touched" popover-trigger="keyup focus">
```

this is what you're looking for: `ng-model="value.min"` or `ng-model="value.max"`

Comment: Thx. I didn't notice it!